# echo active image alt text in <p>

Tags: php, jquery, html, magento

I'm trying to figure out some php code.

I have a slider inside a fancybox popup.
What i need to do is then i click on image it gets me its alt text in  "image-product-name" P class.

```
    <div class="modal-body">
    <button class="close">×</button>
    <div class="UI-IMAGE image">
        <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('core/image')->init($_product, 'image', 'catalog/product')->resize(640, 400) ?>" width="640px" height="400px"
            alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()) ?>"
            title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()) ?>">
    </div>
    <p class="image-product-name"><?php echo $_product->getName() ?></p>
    <?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
    <div class="previews UI-PREVIEWS">
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="#" 
                    title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>"
                    data-image="<?php echo $this->helper('core/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', 'catalog/product', $_image->getFile())->resize(640, 400); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('core/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', 'catalog/product', $_image->getFile())->resize(78, 78); ?>" width="78px" height="78px"
                        alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>"/>
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
```

Right now its just echoes an image name.
What should i change in order to make it echo active image alt text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need javascript for this. In the next example I've used jQuery:

```
$('.imgClass').click(function(){  //When user click on your img
    var altImg = $(this).attr('alt');  //Save the alt attribute into a variable
    $('p.image-product-name').html(altImg); //Place the variable between the p tags;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

without js just change the variable from:

```
   <p class="image-product-name"><?php echo $_product->getName() ?></p>
```

to

```
   <p class="image-product-name"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?></p>
```

pretty straighforward